# How to send current Month in event request in FullCalendar JS?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

With method of mistakes i come across that calendar.getDate().getMonth() works outside this function, but how about inside? This. not work it says that this. is not a function.

```
   <script>
    var todayDate = moment().startOf('day');
    var YM = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM');
    var YESTERDAY = todayDate.clone().subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var TODAY = todayDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var TOMORROW = todayDate.clone().add(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    var month;

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
    {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
            {
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'list', 'timeGrid', 'interaction', 'bootstrap'],
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                //dateAlignment: "month", //week, month
                buttonText:
                    {
                        today: 'today',
                        month: 'month',
                        week: 'week',
                        day: 'day',
                        list: 'list'
                    },
                eventTimeFormat:
                    {
                        hour: 'numeric',
                        minute: '2-digit',
                        meridiem: 'short',
                        hour12: false,
                    },
                navLinks: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                header:
                    {
                        left: 'prev,next today addEventButton',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                    },
                footer:
                    {
                        left: '',
                        center: '',
                        right: ''
                    },
                customButtons:
                    {
                        addEventButton:
                            {
                                text: '+',
                                click: function()
                                {
                                    var dateStr = prompt('Enter a date in YYYY-MM-DD format');
                                    var date = new Date(dateStr + 'T00:00:00'); // will be in local time

                                    if (!isNaN(date.valueOf()))
                                    { // valid?
                                        calendar.addEvent(
                                            {
                                                title: 'dynamic event',
                                                start: date,
                                                allDay: true
                                            });
                                        alert('Great. Now, update your database...');
                                        //update data
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        alert('Invalid date.');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    },
                //height: 700,
                editable: false,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                views:
                    {
                        sevenDays:
                            {
                                type: 'agenda',
                                buttonText: '7 Days',
                                visibleRange: function(currentDate)
                                {
                                    return {
                                        start: currentDate.clone().subtract(2, 'days'),
                                        end: currentDate.clone().add(5, 'days'),
                                    };
                                },
                                duration:
                                    {
                                        days: 7
                                    },
                                dateIncrement:
                                    {
                                        days: 1
                                    },
                            },
                    },
                events:{
                    url: '{{ path('calendar_fetchData', {'id': user.Id}) }}',
                    method: 'POST',
                    extra_params: {
                        month: this.getDate().getMonth(),
                    }
                },
            });

        calendar.render();



    });

</script>
```

I already tried $. and $(#calendar) and calendarEl. but this is not working

It tells me to give more details but this is enough. I can tell youthat i alredy tried answersfrom other topics, they did not works.

Comment: Why do you even need this? fullCalendar will already send the start and end dates to your URL automatically. This is more accurate than sending the month. You simply don't need to do it

Comment: seriously? can you give me a link to doc? what are the data names?

Comment: The parameters are called start and end. It's described here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed

Comment: okay but what if i want other parameters? howto get them inside ?

Comment: what 'other parameters' are you looking for?  You may not think you need to give more details, but you do..... we can't read your mind!  Explain what you are doing and what the issue is as if we are third graders (i.e., step-by-step) so we can follow the issue and you can get the help you want.  Many times when you do that you see the answer yourself.

Comment: If you want to send other parameters you can use the extraParams feature, as you were trying to do. That should work in most cases. My point was only that you didn't need to fetch the month, specifically

Comment: thatnks i used your answer but i want to know why this didn't worked for me, just curious

Comment: it's all about scope. You're not executing inside the context of the calendar - you're providing options to the calendar **before** the calendar exists. `this` cannot refer to the calendar because there is no calendar yet, and you're not inside a callback with scope within the calendar. Also, even if it worked, you're providing a static value, so it would always return the first month displayed, and not reflect any changes. And lastly, the option's name is `extraParams` not `extra_params`!

Comment: then this is useles, how can i then send options from calendar inside calendar if they are not established for now. Why then this getMontn and getDate exists at all.